# python: Pass shared memory array to a C++ funtion in a multiprocessing thread

Tags: python, c++, opencv, shared-memory, python-multiprocessing

I really become desperate.

I am working with Boost.Python to write some OpenCV methods in c++ and get access to them from python. Simplified I want to read a video stream from my webcam in python and display them via a function in c++. I want to do this asynchronously using the python module multiprocessing. It needs to be real time so just converting it is not an option for me (that takes to long adding the time for my calculations before).
So I had the idea to use the shared memory array from multiprocessing module in python.

What I got until now looks almost like that:

*videoStream.py*

```
import displayImage as di #shared object with access to c++ methods
import multiprocessing as mp
import cv2
import ctypes
import numpy as np

def readImage(stream, frame):
  while True:
    check, frame = stream.read()
    if not check:
        break

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

  stream.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#Main
stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
displayImg = di.displayImage()

check, frame = stream.read()

array_size = frame.shape[0] * frame.shape[1] * frame.shape[2]
shared_arr = mp.Array(ctypes.c_uint8, array_size)

np_array = np.frombuffer(shared_arr.get_obj(), dtype=np.uint8)

process_read = mp.Process(target=readImage, args=(stream, np_array))
process_show = mp.Process(target=displayImg.displayImage, args=shared_arr)

process_read.start()
process_show.start()

process_show.join()
process_read.join()
```

*displayImg.cpp*

```
//Some functions and code
void multiThread::displayImage(PyObject* sharedArr){

Py_buffer pybuf;
PyObject_GetBuffer(sharedArr, &pybuf, PyBUF_SIMPLE);
void* vp = pybuf.buf;
unsigned char* img = (unsigned char*)vp;

while(true){
    Mat image = Mat(640, 480, CV_8UC1, img);
    imshow("WebCam Image", image);

    if(waitKey(1) == 27){
        break;
    }
}

destroyAllWindows();
}
```

It compiles and doesn't show any error. But when I want to run it I get:

> int, int, int....
>   did not match C++ signature:
>       displayImage(multiThread {lvalue}, unsigned char*)

So how can I pass the correct pointer to that shared memory array?

Thanks for help!

PS:
I tried as well to pack the shared memory array into another array in python. Then I got no error message but it did not display anything.